# Photo collage of up to 6 photos using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm new to flexbox, and trying to use it to lay out a photo collage of up to 6 photos, like so:
[image: correct]

I want the photos to be laid out as numbered, so that when there are fewer than 6 photos, the position of each photo above remains the same, just with an empty space for the missing photos.

Here's what I've got:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .photo {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .large {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }
        .small {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="photo large">Photo 1</div>
        <div class="photo small">Photo 2</div>
        <div class="photo small">Photo 3</div>
        <div class="photo small">Photo 4</div>
        <div class="photo small">Photo 5</div>
        <div class="photo small">Photo 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is producing this layout:

[image: incorrect]

For some reason, flex-wrap is not putting Photo 3 where I want it, even though there is room for it. I've tried fiddling with justify-content and align-items, but can't seem to get it to work.

Is there anyway to do this without having to introduce more <div>s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS Grid Solution

Since you have no restrictions regarding CSS Grid, have a look at what it can do for you when laying out items in both x and y directions. The [`grid-template-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas) property makes handling this type of layout trivial. You define the template areas in the parent element and then place the children in whichever area(s) you'd like. You can imagine this really opens up what you can do in different responsive/adaptive contexts.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "largetop largetop smalltop1" 
                       "largetop largetop smalltop2" 
                       "smallbottom1 smallbottom2 smallbottom3";
}

.photo-1 {
  grid-area: largetop;
}

.photo-2 {
  grid-area: smallbottom1;
}

.photo-3 {
  grid-area: smallbottom2;
}

.photo-4 {
  grid-area: smalltop1;
}

.photo-5 {
  grid-area: smalltop2;
}

.photo-6 {
  grid-area: smallbottom3;
}

.photo {
  background-color: red;
}

.large {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo photo-1 large">Photo 1</div>
  <div class="photo photo-2 small">Photo 2</div>
  <div class="photo photo-3 small">Photo 3</div>
  <div class="photo photo-4 small">Photo 4</div>
  <div class="photo photo-5 small">Photo 5</div>
  <div class="photo photo-6 small">Photo 6</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahxt90qj/3/)

### Flexbox Solution

Once the large photo takes up the available container space, the following two items wrap to the next row via `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  /* row direction  */
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 400px;
}

.photo {
  background-color: red;
}

.large {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="photo large">Photo 1</div>
    <div class="photo small">Photo 2</div>
    <div class="photo small">Photo 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="photo small">Photo 4</div>
    <div class="photo small">Photo 5</div>
    <div class="photo small">Photo 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping to not have to further segment my container with more divs, because it means the JS that is building the HTML now has to have conditionals based on how many photos are to be laid out.

Is there no way to do without changing the HTML that I have?

Comment: @Jugdish Do you have any restrictions regarding CSS Grid? Can you use it? That's honestly the best way to do this without HTML segmentation.

Comment: Nope, no restriction other than I don't know CSS Grid yet :) I had read that Flexbox was the king of advanced layouts, so thought it should be possible, but if Grid is the best tool for this job, I'll use it!

Comment: @Jugdish I think you'll like the CSS Grid update ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like these as well with the display flex (main axis) just wrap each column in div..

HTML

```
<!-- -- you can divide the container by two and add display: flex (main axis) -- -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- first column -->

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="photo large">Photo 1</div>
            <div class="col-1-parent">
                 <div class="photo col-1-child">Photo 2</div>
                 <div class="photo col-1-child">Photo 3</div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- second column -->


        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="photo col-2-child">Photo 4</div>
            <div class="photo col-2-child">Photo 5</div>
            <div class="photo col-2-child">Photo 6</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
        }

        .photo{
            background-color: red;
        }

        /*--- first column here ---*/

        .col-1{
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .large{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        .col-1-parent{
            display: flex;
        }

        .col-1-child {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        /*--- Second column here ---*/

        .col-2{
            width: 200px;
            height: 600px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .col-2 .col-2-child{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
```